# GitHub Action: `Could not resolve to a node with the gloabl id of 'null'`

Tags: bash, github-actions

My GitHub action to create an issue is now failing when trying to add a milestone. My current workflow looks like this: (note that some aspects have been anonymized for privacy)

```
      - name: create-issue
        id: create-issue
        env:
          title: ${{ github.event.pull_request.title }}
          writer: ${{ steps.get-writer.outputs.writer }}
          version: "(v0.32)"
          pr_number: ${{ github.event.pull_request.number }}
        run: |
          echo "title should be $title"
          echo "writer should be $writer"
          data=$( cat << EOT
          {
              "title": "Document PR #$pr_number - ${title//[\'\"\\\`]/} $version",
              "body": "Determine whether #$pr_number needs any release notes or other documentation updates",
              "assignees": [ "$writer" ],
              "labels": [ "Area: Documentation" ]
          }
          EOT
          )

          response=$(curl --request POST \
          --url "myurl" \
          --header "Cookie: logged_in=no" \
          --header "Authorization: Bearer ${{ xxsecretxx }}" \
          --header "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" \
          --data "$data")

          issue_node_id=$(echo "$response" | jq '.node_id')
          echo 'ISSUE_NODE_ID='$issue_node_id >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Add to Milestone
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ xxsecretxx }}
          ISSUE_ID: $ISSUE_NODE_ID

        run: |
           item_id="$( gh api graphql -f query='
            mutation($issueid:ID!, $milestone:ID) {
             updateIssue(input: {milestoneId: $milestone, id: $issueid}) {
                issue {
                  id
                }
              }
            }' -f milestone="xxxxx" -f issueid=$ISSUE_NODE_ID)"
```

The failure is coming with this error:
`gh: Could not resolve to a node with the global id of 'null' Error: Process completed with exit code 1.`

For what reason would the node_id be set to 'null'?

Comment: Lint your workflow with https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/. From the first look, `ISSUE_ID` should `ISSUE_NODE_ID` and it needs to be properly set using `env` context as set in the previous step. There could be more issues. Linting should be helpful.